# mysql view schema collation

Tags: mysql, database-schema, collation

Is it possible to view the collation for a specific schema via sql?  I have found examples for individual columns but its the schema im hoping to lookup.

So as a **guess** something like

`SELECT 'collation_info' FROM DB_NAME`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can view this information from `information_schema`.`schemata` table -

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
  WHERE schema_name = 'DB_NAME';
```

Or try `SHOW CREATE DATABASE` statement.